Why does FFmpeg extract my video's AAC stream with broken duration/bitrate information?
I have an MKV file recorded with OBS that contains one video and two (AAC) audio streams. I would like the first audio stream isolated as a playable audio file without re-encoding anything. My attempts generated an audio file with either incorrect or non-existant duration and bitrate information.
I ran the following FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i v.mkv -acodec copy a.aac
When playing the resulting file in any media player, the displayed duration keeps changing. In VLC for Android, seeking stops the playback. Running ffprobe on it reports the following:
Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from 'C:\Users\Sebb\a.aac':
  Duration: 68:20:39.33, bitrate: 4 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 4 kb/s

The real duration of the stream should be 1:39:42 and the bitrate is obviously higher.
Re-encoding the file completely fixes the issue, but I would like to avoid this in case there is a simple workaround. I've tried adding -analyzeduration 99999999 to the extraction command but the outcome was the same.
I am using ffmpeg version 4.3.1 installed through pip on Windows 10.

ffmpeg -i v.mkv -vn -sn -acodec copy a.m4a

@Gyan Thank you, using the m4a extension fixed the issue.
